# Add second y axis based on same dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a boxplot using `ggplot2`, and need to have two axes from the same data frame representing two different scales. Essentially I am plotting surface area to volume ratios per two different species for three appendages, and one of the appendages has a very high SA:V ratio in comparison to the other two, which makes it difficult to have them all on the same graph.

I've recreated my data and code for the boxplot to demonstrate what I am talking about. If possible I would like the dorsal fins to be displayed on the same graph, but on a different y axis scale (that will also be shown on the graph) just so the boxes of the boxplot are all visible.

```
SAV <- c(seq(.35, .7, .01), seq(.09, .125, .001), seq(.09, .125, .001))
Type <- c(rep("Pectoral Fin", 36), rep("Dorsal fin", 36), rep("Fluke", 36))
Species <- c(rep(c(rep("Sp1", 18), rep("Sp2", 18)), 3))
appendage <- data.frame(SAV, Type, Species)

ggplot(aes(y = appendage$SAV, 
           x = factor(appendage$Type, levels = c("Dorsal fin", "Fluke")),
           fill = appendage$Species), 
       data = appendage) + 
 geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
 labs(y = expression("SA:V("*cm^-1*")"), x="") + 
 scale_x_discrete(labels = c("PF", "DF", "F")) + 
 scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "gray"))
```

If any one could help me with this that would be great!

[image]

Comment: While the answer from @hpesoj626 is probably what you are looking for you would really need to tell your audience about the differing scales -so they do not misinterpret the data (people might glance over the scales). I might even recommend doing separate graphs.

Comment: I agree that it may be confusing. My only qualm with making separate graphs is that I have similarly formatted plots throughout my analyses and I'd like them to be consistent. But I'm going to see how the final result looks and take it from there! Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use `facet_wrap`.

```
appendage %>% 
  mutate(
    Type = factor(Type, 
                  levels = c("Dorsal fin", "Fluke", "Pectoral Fin"), 
                  labels = c("DF", "PF", "F"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Type, SAV, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) + 
  labs(y=expression("SA:V("*cm^-1*")"),x="") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","gray")) + 
  facet_wrap(~Type, scales="free") + 
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way to combine these 3 graphs so the scale of .09-.12 on the left and the scale of 0.4 -0.7?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean @user33993. But perhaps, as commented in your OP, separate boxplots might be more appropriate for your case.

Answer (score 0):

First off, like what others have commented, I do **not** recommend this type of plot. Dual axes have a tendency to make comparisons harder, & visually confuse the audience even when they are aware of it.

That said, it is possible to achieve this using `ggplot2`, & I'll show one approach below, once we get past several other issues in the original code:

**Issue 1**: You are passing a data frame to `ggplot()`. The dollar sign `$` has no place in `aes()` in such cases.

Instead of:

```
ggplot(aes(y = appendage$SAV, 
           x = factor(appendage$Type), # ignore the levels for now; see next issue
           fill = appendage$Species), 
       data = appendage) + 
...
```

Use:

```
ggplot(aes(y = SAV, 
           x = factor(Type),
           fill = Species), 
       data = appendage) + 
...
```

**Issue 2**: Which appendage has the extraordinarily high SA:V?

From the code used to generate the sample dataset, it should be "Pectoral Fin", but the final result shows "DF". I assume the mapping between full terms & axis labels to be:

- "Pectoral Fin" -> "PF"
- "Dorsal fin" -> "DF"
- "Fin" -> "F"

... so this looks like a slip up between passing Type as a factor to the x parameter in `aes()`, and setting the axis labels in `scale_x_discrete()`.

Since you're using `factor()`, it would be neater to set the labels there as well. Keeping it in the same place makes such things easier to spot.

Instead of:

```
ggplot(aes(y = SAV, 
           x = factor(Type, levels = c("Dorsal fin", "Fluke")),
           fill = Species), 
       data = appendage) + 
...
```

Use:

```
ggplot(aes(y = SAV,
           x = factor(Type, 
                      levels = c("Dorsal fin", "Fluke", "Pectoral Fin"),
                      labels = c("DF", "F", "PF")),
           fill = Species),
       data = appendage) +
...
```

I switched the order of factors as I feel it makes (marginally) more sense visually for the x-axis category corresponding to the secondary y-axis (typically on the right) to be on the right of other x-axis categories. You can change that if this isn't the desired case. Just make sure both `levels = ...` and `labels = ...` are changed together.

**Solution for secondary y-axis**

1. Manually re-scale the values of the offending appendage (whichever fin that turns out to be) until its range is somewhat similar to that of other appendages. (In the example below, I used a simple division of `y / 5`, but more complicated functions can be used too.)
2. Specify the `sec.axis()` option for the y-axis, using the inverse of the re-scaling function as the transformation. (In this case `y * 5`.)
3. Label the original y-axis (left) and the secondary y-axis (right) accordingly to make it clear which appendage(s) each axis's scale applies to.

Final code + result:

```
k = 5 #rescale factor

ggplot(aes(y = ifelse(Type == "Pectoral Fin", 
                      SAV / k, SAV),
           x = factor(Type, 
                      levels = c("Dorsal fin", "Fluke", "Pectoral Fin"),
                      labels = c("DF", "F", "PF")),
           fill = Species),
       data = appendage) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~. * k,
                                         name = expression("SA:V ("*cm^-1*") PF"))) +
  labs(y = expression("SA:V ("*cm^-1*") DF / F"), x = "") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "gray"))
```

[image: plot]